# Toast notification with binding and styling

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, toast

Greetings for the day!

I am totally new to UWP. I am building a music playing app in UWP, which plays song even when windows is locked.
To show to the player on lock screen I am trying to use Toast notification. In toast notification we can using binding to show the progress.

```
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>Default Audio Toast</text>
            <text>This toast's audio is not specified, and thus uses the system default.</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>

</toast>
```

I want to know can I show the normal XAML page along with all the bindings and styling in toast notification?
Is there any way to show the notification to the center of the screen for time till user logs in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use XAML in toast notification, unfortunately.

Comment: is there any way to make Toasted notification buttons to work when windows is locked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057690/toasted-notifications-action-button-is-not-working-on-lock-screen